# Boto limiting results to 1000 for ec2.get_spot_price_history()?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I am using the boto library to access information from AWS EC2's get_spot_price_history function. I've noticed it limits results to 1000 - even though I'm not setting max_results. Is there any way to get more than 1000 results? Even if I set max_results to 2000, I still only get 1000 results.

I don't see anything in the boto code that limits results to 1000, which is puzzling. Here is a sample script I am using that illustrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto
import boto.ec2
ec2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-1", aws_access_key_id="KEY", aws_secret_access_key="SECRET")

start = '2013-11-17T00:14:45.000Z'
end =   '2013-12-17T00:14:45.000Z'

output = ec2.get_spot_price_history(start_time=start, end_time=end, availability_zone="us-west-1a")
print "Length: %d" % (len(output))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be due to behavior of the underlying AWS EC2 API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html

```
MaxResults
    The maximum number of items to return for this call. The call also returns a token that you can specify in a subsequent call to get the next set of results.
    Type: Integer
    Default: The call returns all items.
    Constraint: If the value is greater than 1000, we return only 1000 items.
    Required: No
```

It seems Amazon returns a token which you can use in subsequent requests, but I haven't seen that `boto` exposes that token yet. I am also trying to get information about more than 1000 instances.

Edit: Looks like a bug was filed that was fixed already: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/1957
The list that is being returned should be a ResultSet, which will have `nextToken` for you.